# Show pm2 command that started a process

Tags: node.js, pm2

From my linux machine, typing `pm2 status` shows me

```
│ App name     │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status  │ restart │ uptime │ memory      │ watching │
├──────────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────────────┼──────────┤
│ gamatrix-dev │ 0  │ fork │ 0     │ stopped │ 0       │ 0      │ 0 B         │ disabled │
│ gamatrix     │ 1  │ fork │ 22779 │ online  │ 10      │ 2D     │ 78.793 MB   │ disabled │
│ elevacad     │ 2  │ fork │ 14106 │ online  │ 13      │ 3D     │ 36.227 MB   │ disabled │
```

I'm pretty sure for the last two lines, they were initiated by a command like `pm2 start someapp.js`.  Is there a way to know what value `someapp.js` really was that started the process?

Comment: `pm2 describe`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782660/3160483

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned in a comment, use

```
pm2 describe
```

That will produce copious output similar to the following:

```
┌───────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ status            │ online                                                                              │
│ name              │ random                                                                              │
│ namespace         │ default                                                                             │
│ version           │ 1.0.0                                                                               │
│ restarts          │ 0                                                                                   │
│ uptime            │ 107m                                                                                │
│ script path       │ /home/pi/checkout/random-monitor.ts                                                 │
│ script args       │ N/A                                                                                 │
│ error log path    │ /home/pi/.pm2/logs/random-error.log                                                 │
│ out log path      │ /home/pi/.pm2/logs/random-out.log                                                   │
│ pid path          │ /home/pi/.pm2/pids/random-1.pid                                                     │
│ interpreter       │ /home/pi/.nvm/versions/node/v12.19.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/.bin/ts-node │
│ interpreter args  │ N/A                                                                                 │
│ script id         │ 1                                                                                   │
│ exec cwd          │ /home/pi/checkout                                                                   │
│ exec mode         │ fork_mode                                                                           │
│ node.js version   │ 12.19.0                                                                             │
│ node env          │ N/A                                                                                 │
│ watch & reload    │ ✘                                                                                   │
│ unstable restarts │ 0                                                                                   │
│ created at        │ 2020-11-18T00:17:04.623Z                                                            │
└───────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The `interpreter`, `interpreter args`, `script path` and `script args` should give you what you are after. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40782660/1518546) to a similar question.

Note: For the sake of completeness, the actual command requires a name or argument for which process you'd like information about. In the case above the full command is `pm2 describe random` where `random` above is the name of the process as you can tell from the output. You may run `pm2 status` to get a list of processes along with their id and name.

Note: I left the command above listed as just `pm2 describe` without the argument to avoid potentially confusing error messages for cut and paste users. I think the error message `pm2 describe` produces indicating a missing required argument is far less confusing than one stating that "random" is not found or even worse if I listed the argument as `name|id` which would cause the output to be piped to the program `id` that may or may not exist depending on the platform on which you are running.