# How to view pm2 command line arguments passed to Node.js at startup?

Tags: node.js, pm2

As a server administrator, I would like to view the command line arguments that a Node.js service was started with using pm2. (The ones that Node.js uses via `process.argv`)

The command `pm2 show my-service-name` gives information around that service but does not display the command that was used to start it.

e.g. `pm2 start index.js -- myProcessArgument`

Can anyone please tell me where I can see `myProcessArgument`, or even better, the full line above?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All you have to do is :

```
pm2 describe <id of application or name>
```

**Example**

```
pm2 describe 1 or pm2 describe app
```

For Json Output

```
pm2 jlist
```

The output should have `script args` tag that will describe all command line arguments,You can find more information [here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#42-starts)

Comment: does that show ALL of the command-line args? it looks truncated on my system

Comment: you can try `pm2 jlist` it should output raw JSON format